# Get a specific octet from the string representation of an IPv4 address

Tags: string, powershell, ip-address

I have a variable named `$Ip`. This variable has an IP inside like "172.13.23.34". I would like to get the 3rd octet or the next character between 172.13. and .34 which is a string number 23 in this case and store in another variable to set up a VLANID with the command below.

```
$Ip = 172.13.23.34
$VLANID = ?
Set-Netadapter -Name "Ethernet" -VlanID $VLANID
```

How can I get this specific information?

Comment: I commend to your attention the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7), which will fully enable you to do exactly what you want.

Comment: `$Ip = '172.13.23.34'; $VLANID = $Ip.Split('.')[2]; $VLANID` returns `23`…

Comment: Thank you very much JosefZ!

Comment: Djair Silva, while I'm never too sure on the exact _implicit_ notification rules, the reliable way to notify someone of a follow-up comment is to @-mention them, which would be @JosefZ in this case. Also, allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment.

Answer (score 4):

While [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), the regex-based string-splitting *operator*, or the literal-substring-based [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Split) *method* are the proper tools for splitting a string into tokens by separators in general, there's an easier solution in your case:

```
# Trick: [version] splits the string into its numerical components.
#        The .Build property value corresponds to the 3rd octet.
PS> ([version] '172.13.23.34').Build
23
```

The [`[version]` (`System.Version`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version) type, intended for version numbers, understands 4-component numbers separated by `.`, which look like IPv4 addresses. The properties of such instances map onto the octets of an IPv4 address as follows:

- `.Major` ... 1st octet (`172`)
- `.Minor` ... 2nd octet (`13`)
- `.Build` ... 3rd octet (`23`)
- `.Revision` ... 4th octet (`34`)

Note:

- If you need *all* octets, consider [iRon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63711365/45375), which more properly uses the `[IPAddress]` type.
- That said, `[version]` has one advantage over `[IPAddress]`: it implements the [`System.IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IComparable) interface, which means that you *compare* IPv4 addresses; e.g.,
  `[version] '172.9.23.34' -lt [version] '172.13.23.34'` is `$true`

Answer (score 2):

Using the .Net [`[IPAddress]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=netcore-3.1) Class:

```
([IPAddress]'172.13.23.34').GetAddressBytes()
172
13
23
34
```