# String of IP Address to usable INT

Tags: powershell, jenkins, ip

Hey I'm trying to get input from user (Jenkins Option) for an IP Address and past it in Configuration file for FortiGate .

I'm trying to do this way :

```
$source_subnet = "240.14.4.5"


    $Subnet = $source_subnet
    
    $Subnetint = [Int64]$Subnet
    
    write-host $Subnetint
```

for example user wrote the ip 240.14.4.5

but im getting this error :

```
Cannot convert value "240.14.4.5" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell - Checking IP Address range based on CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609183/powershell-checking-ip-address-range-based-on-csv-file) or [Get a specific octet from the string representation of an IPv4 address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63710588/1701026) and related question: [Extending accelerated .Net class using the original constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63765349/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

Try converting to `[IPAddress]` first:

```
 ( [ipaddress]"240.14.4.5").Address
```

Comment: When i just run this command on powershell " ( [ipaddress]"240.14.4.5").Address" , I'm received the number " 84152048 " on the output somehow … from where this number coming from ?

Comment: `((5*256+4)*256+14)*256+240`

Comment: so how exactly doing this "  ( [ipaddress]"240.14.4.5").Address " will help to achieve what i I want ?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Note that you need to know the **subnet mask** (number of bits, e.g. `.../24`) to be able to subtract a subnet from an ip address...

Comment: I want to receive string " 1.1.1.1" and convert into usable INT , number

Comment: How does `1.1.1.1` relate to the given ip address `240.14.4.5`? Please, define "usable" as the answer (including the answers in the duplicate questions) already convert an ip address to an `int`. What will be a "usable" for  `240.14.4.5` or `1.1.1.1`? Please add the information to the question, see also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).